# How to read/get googlesheet data in realtime for shiny

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, shinydashboard

I want my Shiny to be able to read my Google Sheet if there is a change in the Google Sheet; right now I am using reactivepoll with intervalMillis = 60000. But with my coding shiny is not updated in minutes, but if I refresh it shiny will display the latest data from google sheet, even if my code is successful then my shiny will refresh every 1 minute and it will cause lag, how do I change my code so that df can be updated every time there is a change in my google sheet

```
df <- reactivePoll(
    intervalMillis = 60000,
    session = session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      sheets <- gs4_find()
      sheets[[1]]
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      df <- range_speedread(ss, sheet = sheet_name, range = "A1:T", guess_max = 10000)
      df$KPI <- as.numeric(df$KPI)
      df$Budget <- as.numeric(df$Budget)
      dfPage likes` <- as.numeric(dfPage likes`)
      df$KPI <- as.numeric(df$KPI)
      df <- filter(df, Budget > 0)
      return(df)
    }
  )
```

and for my dt is like this:

```
datatable(df() %>% select(-c(Engagement, Lead, `Page Like`,Views)), extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
                                 dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                 buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
                               )) %>%
                               formatPercentage("Burn Rate",1) %>% 
                               formatCurrency(c("Budget", "Roll Out Budget", "Cost"),currency = "Rp. ",digits = 2L,mark = ",") %>%
                               formatStyle(
                                 "Burn Rate",
                                 backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(0.95, 1.00), c("#ffc04d", "#66b366", "#fb6666")),
                                 backgroundSize = "80% 90%",
                                 backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat",
                                 color = "black",
                                 backgroundPosition = "center"
                               )
```

Comment: Are you sure the value of `sheets[[1]]` updates when your file is updated? That seems like to be the file ID which is likely to remain constant and not change. Also where is the value of `ss` coming from in your `valueFunc`?

Comment: yes it change, ss is come from my global code which is contained of gs4_get